# Трансляция на сайт через OBS

Tags: php, rtmp, obs

Появились на руках исходники цмски, которая транслирует работу через программу OBS Studio, но я не понимаю как оно все работает.

Вот такой код вписываю в настройках OBS Studio:

```
Тип вещания: пользовательский сервер вещания
url: rtmp://site.ru/live?a176d51ba0481ebf9bd9
ключ потока: логин пользователя подставляется
```

Сайт в свою очередь отдает  тег, с ссылкой на этот же rtmp протокол

```
$rtmp_url = "rtmp://site.rum/live/" . $login;
$hls_url  = "//site.ru/hls/" . $login . ".m3u8";
```

И видео отображается на сайте с компьютера.

Я с этим протоколом не работал еще, да и спросить не у кого как оно работает, поэтому пришел сюда.

Погуглил, и нашел инфу о этом протоколе.

Но так и не понял - это программа OBS Studio отдает данные на ссылку которая указана как URL (rtmp://site.ru/live?a176d51ba0481ebf9bd9), а сайт просто берет и подставляет эту ссылку в , и оно транслирует?...

Если кто то может объяснить, буду рад. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

На сервере который доступен по доменному имени site.ru должна быть программа (например *Adobe Media Server*), которая принимает входящие rtmp подключения.
В зависимости от её настроек производит манипуляции с получаемым(и) видео потоком, а затем по запросу пользователей отдаёт необходимые им потоки на их клиентские машины.

Ссылка которую Вы привели лишь указывает клиентским плеерам на идентификатор трансляции которую нужно запросить у сервера для воспроизведения.